# CSS overriding when using inheritance

Tags: css, overriding

I'm trying to override a CSS class which is used to display an arrow. I want to make the arrow disappear. This class is found in the Liferay theme.

this CSS class:

```
.v-tabsheet-tabitem-selected:after {
    border: 10px solid;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-color: #333 transparent transparent;
    bottom: -6px;
    content: '-';
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 0;
}
```

I did:

```
.v-tabsheet-tabitem-selected:after{
    content: none;    
}
```

It does not seem to work, is there any other way?

Comment: Probably there's a :hover style somewhere that's applying, or some JS that does onmousemove... impossible to say unless you provide more details. what's this a theme for?

Comment: I used the class: .v-tabsheet-tabitem-selected and the selector after

Comment: why are you using `::after`?? shouldn't it be only `:after`??

Comment: @pleasedontbelong Both are correct. Pseudo-elements in CSS3 use double colons. IE8 only supports the single colon notation though, so Nick, if you need compatibility you should stick with single colons.

Comment: this theme is used to provide the CSS to a Liferay / vaadin project. I can't find a :hover now but I'm looking it up

Comment: :o thxs @BoltClock i've learn something today :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the arrow is being drawn with CSS borders, so try overriding it with this:

`.v-tabsheet-tabitem-selected:after {border: none;}`

Comment: thanks for the idea, I already tested that option and it doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe the initial declaration isn't actually being overridden? Try `.v-tabsheet-tabitem-selected:after {border: none !important;}` just to see.

Answer (score 0):

For the CSS you have provided, your cursor position should not be relevant. That means you either have a `:hover` selector applying elsewhere or JavaScript that applies based on mouse events.

Comment: I can't find one for now, but is there a way I can override that?

Comment: Finaly I don't think it's hover related beacause it was a portlet window. So my override doesn't look to work at all. Is there any other way to hide the arrow?